# how to get list values into bot dialog?

Tags: c#, botframework

I need to return list values and show them in bot emulator.

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> Teams;
```

The above list has all the list of team names added to it.

**Code:**

```
 public int GetTeamCount()
    {
        return Teams.Count;
    }

 public List<string> GetTeams()
    {
        var sorted = Teams.OrderBy(p => p.Value);
        List<string> orderedTeams = new List<string>();
        foreach (var e in sorted)
        {
            orderedTeams.Add(e.Key);
        }

        return orderedTeams;
    }
```

The above list will return list of team names. In the emulator when they ask for list of teams and bot should be able to return all team names.

**DialogClass.cs:**

```
 private async Task ActivityReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        Championships champ = new Championships();

        if (activity.Text.Contains("how many teams"))
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"There are {champ.GetTeamCount()} teams.");
        }
        else if (activity.Text.Contains("list of team names"))
        { 
            await context.PostAsync($"There are {champ.GetTeams()}");
        }               
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("My responses are limited. Please ask the right questions. ");
        }

        context.Wait(ActivityReceivedAsync);
    }
```

How can I get list of team names displayed in the below line?

`await context.PostAsync($"There are {champ.GetTeams()}");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can write for you two of the possible responds:

First: create a list of string link the following:

```
var teamNames = "";
champ.GetTeams().Foreach(x => teamNames += x + ",");
teamNames.TrimEnd(',');
await context.PostAsync($"There are {teamNames}");
```

Second: send a message for each team name:

```
await context.PostAsync("There are:");
champ.GetTeams().Foreach(aync(x) => {
        await context.PostAsync(x);
});
```